# Python scraped data showing in "Command line" not imported to CSV

Tags: python, selenium, csv, web-scraping

I am working on a `Scraping` **Project**, data shows in the command line when it starts but in CSV file all data does not get imported to

this is a part of code to display and add data in CSV

```
from selenium import webdriver 
import csv

myFile = open('amazon_test.csv', 'w')
fild_name=['link','title','category','old_price1','old_price2','old_price3','new_price','desc','image']
writer=csv.DictWriter(myFile, fieldnames=fild_name)
writer.writeheader()

driver.get('https://www.amazon.com/international-sales-offers/b/?ie=UTF8&node=15529609011&ref_=nav_navm_intl_deal_btn')#MAIN PAGE OF AMAZON DEALS PAGE


print(links_list[details_product])
writer.writerow({'link': links_list[details_product]})

print('cat>>',cat_title)#PRINT CATEGORY NAME
writer.writerow({'category': cat_title})

writer.writerow({'title': product_title})

print(driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#priceblock_ourprice').text)
writer.writerow({'old_price1': product_old_price_1})

print(driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#price > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(1) > td.a-span12.a-color-secondary.a-size-base > span.priceBlockStrikePriceString.a-text-strike').text)
writer.writerow({'old_price2': product_old_price_1})

print(driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#priceblock_saleprice').text)
writer.writerow({'old_price3': product_old_price_1})

print(driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#priceblock_dealprice').text)
writer.writerow({'new_price': product_new_price})

print(driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#feature-bullets > ul').text)
writer.writerow({'desc': product_desc})

print(driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#landingImage').get_attribute('src'))
writer.writerow({'image': product_image})
```

[image: this image for csv file with empty coulme]

[image: this is script print all data]

Comment: i have same problem

Answer (score 0):

What exactly do you expect? Each time you call `writer.writerow()`, a new *row* is written with the cells indicated in the dict. If you want to write a single row, first prepare your dict with all the keys and data, and then write it in a single `writerow()`, e.g.:

```py
from selenium import webdriver 
import csv

driver.get('https://www.amazon.com/international-sales-offers/b/?ie=UTF8&node=15529609011&ref_=nav_navm_intl_deal_btn')
fild_name=['link','title','category','old_price1','old_price2','old_price3','new_price','desc','image']

with open('amazon_test.csv', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as myFile:

    writer = csv.DictWriter(myFile, fieldnames=fild_name)
    writer.writeheader()

    data = {'link': links_list[details_product],
            'category': cat_title,
            'title': product_title,
            'old_price1': product_old_price_1} # <--- ADD OTHER DATA...
    # write row to CSV
    writer.writerow(data)
```

Comment: thank for your comment, plz correct the problem in my code

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative the best way to do it using `pandas` library.Crate pandas `DataFrame` and import into csv file. I have just provided some of the field to show case how it works.I believe you can do the rest of the stuff.

If you don't have `pandas` installed in you machine just use following command from command prompt.

> pip install pandas

**Code**:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium import webdriver
import pandas as pd

driver=webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.amazon.com/international-sales-offers/b/?ie=UTF8&node=15529609011&ref_=nav_navm_intl_deal_btn')#MAIN PAGE OF AMAZON DEALS PAGE
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//span[@class='a-label a-checkbox-label' and contains(.,'Arts, Crafts & Sewing')]"))).click()
WebDriverWait(driver,15).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"div.a-section.dealContainer")))
link=driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div.a-section.dealContainer #dealTitle").get_attribute("href")
title=driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div.a-section.dealContainer #dealTitle>span").text.strip()
category=driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".a-link-normal.summary>span").text.strip()
newprice=driver.find_element_by_css_selector("span.dealPriceText").text.strip()
imageurl=driver.find_element_by_css_selector("img[src*='https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I']").get_attribute("src")
df=pd.DataFrame([[link,title,category,newprice,imageurl]],columns=['link','title','category','new_price','image'])
df.to_csv('amazon_test.csv',index=False)
```

**Generated csv file.**

[image]

**Please note:-** The output for single record.If you would like to do for rest of element then you have to use `find_elements_by_css_selector()` to get list of elements and then iterate.

Comment: i have more than one product so just last product wich add